# java API for google Authenticator

Tags: java, api, google-authenticator, authenticator

I wanna add two factor authentication using Google Authenticator and was wondering if google provides with java api's. I tried searching for it but din't find any.
Can anyone point me to the java api if there are any.
If not how can i go about using Google Authenticator in my web based java application. 
I am using Spring framework for my existing application

Answer (score 8):

In fact, Google Authenticator has nothing to do with Google services. What you need to look for is TOTP. Research again using TOTP and rfc6238 as keywords and you will find lots of [resources](https://www.google.ch/search?q=totp%20Spring%20framework&oq=totp%20Spring%20framework).

Answer (score 5):

Java library for google authenticator was implemented and can be found here,
https://github.com/wstrange/GoogleAuth

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is too much of a necro-post, but I found [this library](https://github.com/wstrange/GoogleAuth) on GitHub - maybe it can help you (and others looking for the same). :)

**Note:**  this is not an official Google library, but it follows the [RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) spec for *Time-based One-time Password (TOTP)*, and the author looked at the C code for [Google Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator) for reference.